# CosmosDB get number of nested children

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I try to limit the depth on which child objects can be defined on their parent.

Example Child simplified object:

```json
{
    "name": "childgroup",
    "clientId": "1ea87515-63d2-41b8-b327-5a179394bd4c",
    "parentId": "9a6d3b39-3143-492f-b729-417a721640c9",
}
```

Example Root simplified object

```json
{
    "name": "Root",
    "clientId": "1ea87515-63d2-41b8-b327-5a179394bd4c",
    "parentId": null,
}
```

So for now the distinction between a Root and a child is that the Root object has no `parentId`.

I want to limit the user to make a infinite amount of children that depend on the previous parent. So the child from the previous parent is now the parent of a new child object.

Thus i need to check when my users want to make a new object on how "deep" the last child is given the parentId the user provides me.

How could i make this query is cosmosDB semi-efficient?

I could query every parent from the child and count the number for every time it finds a parent, but that seems to inefficient...

Comment: You could save the level as variable in your document e.g. `"level": 3`. It has little impact to your current scheme and as efficiënt as it gets for such queries.

Comment: I could indeed alter the current object to have a level variable in there allready, maybe thats the best option i have. Thanks!